# Incorrect comparison of new data with old ones in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Last data:

```
last=structure(list(ItemRelation = 11111L, CalendarYear = 2018L, DocumentNum = 111L, 
    ship_count = 1L), .Names = c("ItemRelation", "CalendarYear", 
"DocumentNum", "ship_count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

So there is new data, where can be rows which there are in last data:

```
new5=structure(list(ItemRelation = c(11111L, 22222L), CalendarYear = c(2018L, 
2017L), DocumentNum = c(111L, 100L), ship_count = c(1L, 23L)), .Names = c("ItemRelation", 
"CalendarYear", "DocumentNum", "ship_count"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I must compare new data with last by group and left only these rows, which absent in last.

So I do:

```
mydat=new5[!(new5$DocumentNum%in% last$DocumentNum), !(new5$CalendarYear%in% last$CalendarYear),
           !(new5$ItemRelation%in% last$ItemRelation)]
```

and result:

```
  CalendarYear ship_count
2         2017         2
```

it is not correct output. 
The correct output

```
ItemRelation CalendarYear DocumentNum ship_count
      22222         2017         100         23
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you were actually trying to do was

```
new5[!(new5$DocumentNum %in% last$DocumentNum & 
       new5$CalendarYear %in% last$CalendarYear &
       new5$ItemRelation %in% last$ItemRelation), ]


# ItemRelation CalendarYear DocumentNum ship_count
#2       22222         2017         100         23
```

The condition inside the bracket gives us a logical vector which tells which of the rows in `new5` are present in `last`, by adding a negation (`!`) sign we are telling to give us the rows which are not present in `last`.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it with base R and creating an unique field as key:

```
# key for last
last$collapsed <- paste0(last$ItemRelation, last$CalendarYear, last$DocumentNum, last$ship_count)  

# key for new5  
new5$collapsed <- paste0(new5$ItemRelation, new5$CalendarYear, new5$DocumentNum, new5$ship_count)

# filter on the key, rather than many field, and dropping the key with ,-5
new5[!new5$collapsed %in% last$collapsed,-5]

  ItemRelation CalendarYear DocumentNum ship_count
2        22222         2017         100         23
```